# Switch from SQlite to SQL Server Compact database

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-ce

I am working on WP app, I am using a SQLite database that is 32 Mb and I needed to change it to SQL Server Compact Edition database. The problem is that one column in the SQLite database is of type `Text` that may sometimes contain up to 9000 characters.

After converting the database from SQLite to SQL Server CE, this column has a datatype of `NText`
which is taking a lot of space.

So the new SQL Server CE database size is 130 Mb

And when I am trying to open and read it in WP it is giving me `System out of memory` exception.

Any idea of a good solution?

Comment: Is this a limitation in SQl server compact DB , I hope that ErikEJ can answer me as he is a pretty expert in this DB type,Does this means that is SQLite better than compact SQL server ,Did Microsoft notice this major difference?

Comment: I opened the original SQLite in WP and it is working which was not possible in Compact SQL server DB

Answer (score 0):

For columns with more than 4000 characters, your only option is ntext. Have you tried compacting the SQL Compact database?

Comment: Thanks I forgot about compacting the Db but unfortunately it did not help much ,now the compacted Db is 125 Mb ,still big size.

Comment: I tried to isolate the culprit table and open it from Xml file ,now I ended with a small Db 5 Mb and and a big XMl file 24 Mb that is also consumes a lot of memory during loading and ending up with the same out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a limitation in Compact SQL server so I am returning to SQLite instead as I have a database which contains a column contains more than 4000 but less than 6000 .